# 人工知能で学習していない人の顔だという事を判断することは可能でしょうか

Tags: 機械学習

ちょっと気になったので教えて下さい。

人工知能に人の顔(写真)を学習させると、別の写真であっても人物をある程度特定できるようになるというのはイメージできますが、
逆に「この人は今まで学習していない人である」ということも判断させることは可能なのでしょうか。

Comment: [適合率と再現率の問題](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Zellij/20120214/p1)と言えそうです。例えばガンの診断システムがあって、偽陰性を見逃したら患者が死ぬだろうし、偽陽性だったら健康な人を手術してしまうかもしれない。なので目的に合わせてどちらに重きをおくかでシステムをチューニングするわけです。学習していない人を絶対に通さないシステムなら、学習済みの人を学習していないと判別することを許さないといけないかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

「この人は今まで学習していない人である」ということを推論するモデルとシステムを作ることは可能です。単純には、Aさんの学習データを元にAさんを判断するモデル、Bさんの学習データを元にBさんを判断するモデル…がどれも偽を返したなら「学習したことがない人」と判断できるでしょう。

別の目的で作られたモデルやシステムから「この人は今まで学習していない人である」という推論を取り出せるかは、当初の目的次第ではありますが一般には良くない使い方です。たとえばAさんとBさんの両方のデータを元にAさんとBさんどちらの可能性が高いかを判断するシステムに「どちらでも無い人」を判断させてもよい結果は得られないでしょう。

Comment: 最初の例で、全てのモデルでネガティブデータとして学習されていたサンプルは全てのモデルで偽を返しますが、それと未学習データとはどうやって区別するのでしょう? (単純な疑問です)

Comment: その場合は後者の例です。Aさんかそうでない人たち(ネガティブデータ)のどちらに近いかを推測するモデルですので、「どちらでもない人」の判定には向きません

Answer (score 0):

可能です。最近は深層学習（Deep Learning）がよく使われています。むしろ既にレッドオーシャンになりつつある分野ですね。以下のスライドを参考にしてみればいかがでしょうか。

- [Deep Learningと画像認識　～歴史・理論・実践～](http://www.slideshare.net/nlab_utokyo/deep-learning-40959442)

実装ですと以下の記事が面白いかと思います。（これらは写真ではなくアニメでの顔認識ですが、原理は同じです）

- [はじめてのアニメ顔認識 with Chainer](http://qiita.com/homulerdora/items/9a9af1481bf63470731a)
- [Deep Learningでラブライブ！キャラを識別する](http://christina.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/01/23/212541)
- [[Chainer] Deep Learning でアニメ (ゆるゆり) キャラクターを識別する(2015/11/4少し追記)](http://wtkw.net/tech-blog/?p=34)

Comment: pixyさんが挙げられた記事のような通常の顔認識は「学習させた顔かどうか」を判別するものですが、その逆の「学習させていない顔かどうか」を判別できるのか、ということを質問者さんは聞かれているように思います。

Comment: はい。ですので学習セットに含まれていない値に分類された場合、「学習させていない顔」に当たるんじゃないでしょうか。ラブライブの記事を例に取ると、認識した顔がラブライブのキャラではないと判断された場合、ということになります。